# partition method help! Used in Quicksort method

Tags: java, sorting, partitioning, quicksort

I need help figuring out what exactly is wrong with this partitioning code. I have been struggling with it for a few days now, cant seem to wrap my head around it.

The pIdx is the pivot index, left and right are the bounds integer options for the array, and the array a is just an array or stored long values.

```
protected static int partition(long[] a, int left, int right, int pIdx) { 
    //long numbers[] = {4,3,8,9,7,2,1,5};

    long pivot = a[pIdx];
    swap(a, pIdx, right);
    int storeIndex = left;
    for(int i=left; i<right; i++) {
        if(a[i] <= pivot)
            swap(a, i, storeIndex);

    }//for
    swap(a, right, storeIndex);
    return storeIndex;
}//partitio
```

Comment: You're not moving `storeIndex` forward after the swap in the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I tried fixing your code. See if this works for you.

```
protected static int partition(long[] a, int left, int right, int pIdx) { 
    //long numbers[] = {4,3,8,9,7,2,1,5};
    long pivot = a[pIdx];
    swap(a, pIdx, right);
    int storeIndex = left;
    for(int i=left; i<right; i++) {
        if(a[i] < pivot) {
            swap(a, i, storeIndex);
            storeIndex = storeIndex + 1;
        }
    }
    swap(a, storeIndex, right);
    return storeIndex;
}
```